# I want to make an android app that will access the image data stored on cloud. How can I do that?

Tags: android, cloud

I am confused about which cloud server to use. I just want to store about 300 MB of data on cloud and I want my app to download the required images to users device. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Firebase. They allow you to store images up to 10MB, if they are larger than that you can chop it in 10MB chunks. Here's a neat guide: http://technikyle.com/storing-images-in-firebase/